# PowerShell batch script Timeout ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need to have a timeout in powershell code where I'm running batch file, in case the batch file runs for a longer time or gets stuck. I also have a timeout in the batch script `timeout 300> nul` from which I seem to be getting this error and it is just skipping through the timeout and executing next lines. I do not get this error if I remove the timeout from batch script. But I need timeouts at both places, how do I resolve this ?
Error- *ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately.*

PS Code-

```
$bs={
cd D:\files\ 
cmd.exe /c "mybatchfile.bat"
}
$timeoutseconds=800
$j=Start-Job -Scriptblock $bs
if(wait-Job $j -Timeout $timeoutseconds) {Receive-Job $j}
Remove-Job -force $j
```

batch script is something like this

```
cmd1
cmd2
timeout 300> nul
cmd3
```

Comment: First of all you should use ```%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 300 /NoBreak 1>NUL```. Second, it would certainly help if you actually show us the commands you've replaced with `cmd1`, `cmd2` and `cmd3`. Additionally I do not understand why you're changing directory using the `cd` alias as opposed to `Set-Location` or one of its less confusing aliases, `sl`, for instance.

Comment: It is likely that at least `cmd2` would need to be ```start "" "cmd2"``` or similar.

Comment: @Compo actually I will be modifying this to run a remote conputer so I used cd to navigate to the dir, I will check out Set-Location. The command in batch script are for service restarting and killing some tasks so I am putting a timeout in between the steps.

Comment: As an aside: There's no need to use `cmd /c` in order to execute a batch file - simply invoke it _directly_, though note that PowerShell - by security-minded design - requires prefix ``.\`` in order to execute a batch file in the _current directory_, in order to signal the intent to target an executable there explicitly. Thus, replace `cmd.exe /c "mybatchfile.bat"` with `.\mybatchfile.bat`

Answer (score 3):

- **Whenever `timeout.exe` detects that its *stdin* input stream is *redirected* (not attached to a console), it *abort*s** with the error message you saw.
- Because of how **background jobs launched with [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job)** are implemented, whatever **child processes** you run from the job's script block ***invariably* see stdin as *redirected*, so you won't be able to call `timeout.exe` *directly***.<sup>[1]</sup>

There are two **workarounds**:

- **Call `timeout.exe` via `cmd.exe`'s internal [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) command**:

  - However, this requires calling `start` *without* `/B` in order to execute the `timeout.exe` in a *new window*, whose stdin input by definition *isn't* redirected.
  - In turn, because `start` lacks a way to *hide* such a window, the closest you can come is to use `/MIN` in order to *minimize* it; a minimal example:

    ```
    Start-Job {
      # Simulate calling a batch file (cmd /c)
      # inside of which the `start` call is made,
      # waiting for 5 seconds in this example.
      cmd /c start /min timeout.exe 5
    } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
    ```
- Preferably, **use *thread*-based background jobs, where this problem doesn't arise**:

  - **[`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob)** runs your script block in a separate thread *in the same process*, and stdin redirection isn't involved; also, because no new PowerShell (child) process must be started, thread jobs are faster to create and require fewer resources.

    - `Start-ThreadJob` is part of the [`ThreadJob` module](https://github.com/PowerShell/ThreadJob), which *comes with* [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), and can be *installed on demand* in *Windows PowerShell* (e.g., with `Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser ThreadJob`)
  - Since `Start-ThreadJob` also integrates with PowerShell's job-management infrastructure and shares the core parameter syntax with `Start-Job`, all that should be necessary is to replace `Start-Job` with `Start-ThreadJob` in your code.

---

<sup>[1] Unless there is a way to reattach stdin to the console in a `timeout.exe` call - I'm not aware of such a feature, however (`<CON` creates an `Access denied` error).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested to add a delay in another way. One alternative is to wait with:

```
REM # waits a delay before refresh status of service
ping localhost
```

Indeed I had similar remote PowerShell issue in a scenario with a GitLab agent install script on remote server. By replacing `timeout` with `ping`, the script does not finish anymore with an error.

Comment: So how do you control _the length_ of this delay? Note that the initial post tries to use `300` seconds - i.e. _5 minutes_. By contrast, it looks like your solution is hard-coded to _3 seconds_ (plus change), due to `ping.exe` defaulting to 4 tries.

Comment: You can add parameters to ping to retry, number of count maybe - n 300